# Html ActionLink run time error: 'Value cannot be null or empty. but value is not null or empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use an `@Html.ActionLink` for a clickable link in my view, however I get a run time exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Value cannot be null or empty.
>   Parameter name: linkText

The first param of `Html.ActionLink` is `linkText`, and as you can see from my code below, it is indeed not null or empty.

```
                    @foreach (var o in Model.Results)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.ActionLink(o.Person.FirstName, "Detail", "Player", new { selectedPlayerID = o.Person.IDPerson, referringController = "ValidationHistory" }, null)</td>
                            <td>@o.Person.FirstName</td>
                            <td>@o.Person.LastName</td>
                            <td>@o.Person.SocialSecurityNumber</td>
```

Below is a screen shot of the page, at the top I embedded a @(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(o.Person.FirstName) ? "null/ws": o.Person.FirstName) 
as you can see, it is indeed not null or empty.

[image]

Per request, below is the entire portion of the cshtml file that pertains to this issue.

```
<div class="col-md-10 text-center">
    @if (Model.Results.Count == 0)
    {
        <h3>No Data to Display</h3>
        <h3>Please Try Different Search Parameters</h3>
    }
    else
    {
        <div id="tablecontaner" class="col-md-10 text-left">
            <table id="PVSearchReport" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;padding:10px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>SSN</th>
                        <th>IRS / TIN</th>
                        <th>DMF Details</th>
                        <th>List Matches</th>
                        <th>Executed At</th>
                        <th>Executed By</th>
                        <th>Club ID</th>
                        <th>Lists</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var o in Model.Results)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.ActionLink(o.Person.FirstName, "Detail", "Player", new { selectedPlayerID = o.Person.IDPerson, referringController = "ValidationHistory" }, null)</td>
                            <td>@o.Person.FirstName</td>
                            <td>@o.Person.LastName</td>
                            <td>@o.Person.SocialSecurityNumber</td>

                            <td>@o.Validation_Results.IRSOk</td><!--IRS/TIN-->
                            <td>@o.Validation_Results.DMFOk</td><!--DMF Details-->
                            <td>@o.Validation_Results.ListOk</td><!--List Matches-->
                            <td>@o.Validation_Results.ExecutedAt<!--Executed At-->
                            <td>@o.Validation_Results.ExecutedBy</td><!--Executed By-->
                            <td>@o.Person.ClubID</td>
                            <td>@o.ListMatches</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>        
            </table>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Clearly, FirstName *is* null or empty. I don't understand how we can see from your code that it isn't. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It shouldn't be. I handled that on the back end, and it someone was null it should have created a new Person with the name NO NAME. Also it is displaying elsewhere on the page.. I can add some null checking and see if this works.

Comment: Could it be something regarding deserialization, that you did indeed return a person with a first name from the backend, but the frontend somehow didn't deserialize properly so it doesn't have it?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen This is possible, although I am not sure how I can confirm that? Any Ideas?

Comment: I would still try to simply output the text to the page with something like `@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(o.Person.FirstName) ? "null/ws" : o.Person.FirstName)` and see what it outputs.

Comment: I still want to know how we can see from your code that it isn't null or empty. I think you have some assumptions about what your code is supposed to be doing that doesn't hold true. There is no way for us to see from your code what the content of those objects look like, there's no guarantee obvious in that code that this property holds value. Well, other than the fact that it throws an exception at runtime which indicates quite clearly that it doesn't.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen @(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(o.Person.FirstName) ? "null/ws" : o.Person.FirstName) just produced on my screen: NOT NOT NOT Nick Nick NOT NOT Nick NOT NOT NOT NOT NOT NOT NOT Connor Connor Trina Trina Connor John Billie Ramadugula Seiji Mary Trina Jerome Sonya Latanya Lonnie Lovella Leonardo Trina Fabina Billie Seiji Sonya Seiji Leonardo Shelby Leonardo Trina Douglas Connor Kate Kristin KRISTI Fabina Fabina Jay Brian Warren Seiji Alex John Ramadugula Fabina Seiji Seiji Sonya Sonya Connor Billie Sonya Billie Mary John NOT Kristin Connor    . . . . .

Comment: Just produced what? Nothing?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen check my OP, I posted the results of @(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(o.Person.FirstName) ? "null/ws" : o.Person.FirstName) to show you

Comment: You should check all cshtml file, may be it show exception at line of code before

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen you were right, somewhere within the 233 results I had a null.. even though I thought I had it accounted for....

Comment: Good that you found it, one less bug on the internet :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

1. First check **Model** null or not,Then after check
               **o.Person.FirstName** null or not.

   ```
           ## Check Model Like: ##

            - @if(Model != null && Model.Count() != 0)
               {
                 foreach (var o in Model.Results)
                 {
                   ---------
                 }
               }
           ## Check Record Like: ##
           if(o.Person!=null)
           {
            -----------
           }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it.
You need check null before using `o?.Person?.FirstName` and `o?.Person?.IDPerson`
If C# 5 you can use `o.Person.FirstName != null ? o.Person.FirstName : "Default Value"`
This code worked

```
  <td>@Html.ActionLink(o?.Person?.FirstName, "Detail", "Player", 
new { selectedPlayerID = o?.Person?.IDPerson, referringController = "ValidationHistory" }, null)</td>
```

Comment: If `o` or `o.Person` was null, you'd get a NullReferenceException, not an ArgumentException...

Comment: did you check it? o.Person.FirstName is null that mean ArgumentException

Comment: @HereticMonkey Since linkText is first argument of ActionLink probably o.Person is null

Comment: @PauloCampez `o.Person` is not what you pass to `ActionLink`; you pass `o.Person.FirstName`. `o.Person.FirstName` is what is null, not `o.Person`.

Comment: O.Person isn't null, I have it displaying fine on the rest of the page.

Comment: I did, as others have pointed out, your premise is wrong. If what you're saying is wrong, was wrong, you'd get a NullReferenceException. If you're unable to reproduce a problem you should post a comment, not an answer.

Comment: What I mean is that instead of posting an answer, you should post a comment on the question, if you're unable to reproduce the problem. If either `o` or `o.Person` was null, OP would get a NullReferenceException, not a ArgumentException.

Comment: @HienNguyen Just realized I cannot use null propergating operation. I am using C# 5 and this requires version 6 of the language or greater.

Comment: If you use C# 5 you can change to o.Person.FirstName != null ? o.Person.FirstName : "Default Value"

Comment: @HienNguyen ok, thank you for your time. Please check my original post. I have updated it to prove it isn't null, so this fix won't work.

Comment: Can you post all cshtml file? may exception from different line of code

Comment: @HienNguyen Yes, one moment.

Comment: @HienNguyen Ok, I did not post entire cshtml file, but this should be all that you need...

Comment: is it still exception when you check lastname is null?

Comment: @HienNguyen no, it's an argument exception for the ActionLink

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in my original post. There were some empty strings being returned.

To solve:

```
                        @if (o.Person.FirstName == null || o.Person.FirstName == "" || o.Person.FirstName == "NOT")
                        {
                            <td>Not Found</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>@Html.ActionLink(o.Person.FirstName, "Detail", "Player", new { selectedPlayerID = o.Person.IDPerson, referringController = "ValidationHistory" }, null)</td>
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

See, You need to check first in loop **o.Person**   this 'Person' object is null or not and other is inside Person object FirstName is null or not, you can handle it like this:

```
 if(o.Person!=null)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(o.Person.FirstName ?? "Not Found", "Detail", "Player", new { selectedPlayerID = o.Person.IDPerson, referringController = "ValidationHistory" }, null)
    }
```